# GHC Generics behavior seems to differ in GHCi

Tags: generics, haskell, ghc, ghci

I've been trying to do a little bit of abstraction over data types, and I've encountered a situation with GHC's generics that seems a little odd. Here is my basic set of declarations:

```
class GFields f where
    gfields :: f a -> [String]

instance (GFields c) => GFields (D1 i c) where
    gfields = gfields . unM1

instance (GFields fs) => GFields (C1 i fs) where
    gfields = gfields . unM1

instance (GFields f, GFields fs) => GFields (f :*: fs) where
    gfields (f :*: fs) = gfields f ++ gfields fs

instance (Selector s) => GFields (S1 s r) where
    gfields = (:[]) . selName

data Thing = Thing { foo :: String, bar :: Int }
    deriving (Generic)
```

Trying to use this in GHCi gives me `Prelude.undefined` if I give it an undefined value:

```
> gfields $ from (undefined :: Thing)
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

However, if I try running some of the expected instance by hand (just grabbing a single field), I get what I would expect:

```
> selName $ (\(l :*: r) -> l) $ unM1 $ unM1 $ from (undefined :: Thing)
"foo"
```

Why do I get `Prelude.undefined` in one, but not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this was interesting, what you have there isn't actually quite what's done, the actual code after the inlining is

```
main = print
    . (\(l :*: r) -> selName l ++ selName r)
    . unM1
    . unM1
    . from
    $ (undefined :: Thing)
```

However, changing `\(l :*: r) -> selName l ++ selName r`  to what you had doesn't crash. So the difference is clearly in this line. The obvious thought, that there's something bad about the right field is quickly disproved since `\(l :*: r) -> r` still runs.

We can see that the only nonbottom results are of the form `(\l :*: r -> ???)` where ??? is either `l` or `r`. Nothing else.

So let's take a look at the derived instance with `-ddump-deriv`.

```
from (Thing g1_atM g2_atN) = M1 (M1 (M1 (K1 g1_atM) :*: M1 (K1 g2_atN)))
```

Notice that this is strict in the constructor. So we must not be strict in the result of `from undefined` because the code will crash. So now we're kinda walking on a house of cards here, since forcing any part of this will crash our program. The interesting bit is that

```
-- The derived selectors
instance Selector S1_0_0Thing where
  selName _ = "foo"

instance Selector S1_0_1Thing where
  selName _ = "bar"
```

isn't strict in it's argument. So here's the catch, your code all compiles down to the constant `"foo"` because `selName` is constant, we don't use any of the previous computations; it's a compile time computation. However, if we do any sort of computation with `l` and `r` in that lambda, than when we use `selName` or do anything to see the result, we force the lambda to run, but since `l :*: r` is really bottom, we crash.

As a quick demonstration, this will crash

```
main = (`seq` putStrLn "Crashes")
       . (\(l :*: r) -> ())
       . unM1
       . unM1
       . from
       $ (undefined :: Thing)
```

But this will not

```
main = (const $ putStrLn "Crashes")
       . (\(l :*: r) -> ())
       . unM1
       . unM1
       . from
       $ (undefined :: Thing)
```

TLDR, just make each of the fields undefined, but the toplevel constructor shouldn't be bottom.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that none of your instances force the argument in any way, except this one:

```
instance (GFields f, GFields fs) => GFields (f :*: fs) where
  gfields (f :*: fs) = gfields f ++ gfields fs
```

You're aiming to pass `undefined` to your function, so you have to be very careful in forcing the arguments. The argument is only there to guide the type-checker, it can't be looked at.

The fix is easy. Make the pattern lazy (or *irrefutable*, as the Haskell Report calls it):

```
instance (GFields f, GFields fs) => GFields (f :*: fs) where
  gfields ~(f :*: fs) = gfields f ++ gfields fs
```

This way, the match doesn't actually force the value. It will instead always succeed, and the use of `f` and `fs` translates into applications of selector functions.

With this change, your program works:

```
ghci> gfields $ from (undefined :: Thing)
["foo","bar"]
```

Your other program works because you call `selName` on the *outside*:

```
ghci> selName $ (\(l :*: r) -> l) $ unM1 $ unM1 $ from (undefined :: Thing)
"foo"
```

Now even though you have the pattern match on the pair in the expression, only the type
of the argument of `selName` is relevant for the result. But this expression isn't exactly
the same as your first test program, as the different results demonstrate and as jozefg
further explains in his answer.